# User-user suggestions with collaborative filtering (recommendation system)

Tags: binary-data, similarities, recommender-system, cosine-similarity

I have a binary matrix `N x N` where both rows and columns represent users of a website. If `matix[i,j] = 1` it means that `user i` liked the `user j` (posts). On the other sied, not necessarily `matix[j,i] = 1` because it could be that `user j` **did not like** `user i`' posts. I would like, given a `user k`, to suggest the top 10 users to follow. I think this problem can be solved using a collaborative filtering. I did some research, but I only found solutions based on matrices where columns and rows contains different items, e.g. users-songs, users-movies, users-items, etc. 
Would it make sense to apply what is commonly known as `ITEM-ITEM` (as described in this [post](https://medium.com/@victorkohler/item-item-collaborative-filtering-with-binary-or-unary-data-e8f0b465b2c3))?:

**Item-item summary**:

1. Normalize user vectors to unit vectors.
2. Construct a new item by item matrix.
3. Compute the cosine similarity between all items in the
   matrix.